# How to stop receiving spam emails from Apple?

Tags: email, apple-id, spam, privacy

Over the last couple of weeks, I have received several spam emails from Apple trying to get me to sign up for Apple Arcade or Apple Fitness+. It's very disheartening but not at all surprising that a company that used to pride itself on its premium user experience is resorting to such crass marketing tactics.

Is there any way to get them to cut this crap out? I can't just block all emails from an apple.com address since I also occasionally get important correspondences from them.

These emails have no link to unsubscribe. As near as I can tell, they are genuine emails from Apple and show no signs of being spam. (Correct sender, headers, images from Apple's servers, links go to apple.com, etc.)

I have already unchecked all of the available checkboxes in the privacy section of appleid.apple.com regarding email I receive from them:

[image]

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Are you _sure_ they're actually from Apple and not SPAM?

Comment: That's a good question, and yes, I'm sure. I've edited my original post to mention this.

Answer (score 1):

You describe what look like legitimate marketing emails (legitimate as in Apple did in fact send them to your email) and the bottom of every mail I have received either has a general "subscribe" link that takes you to an Apple ID landing page or a specific link to remove yourself from commercial emails.

> If you prefer not to receive commercial email from Apple, or if you’ve changed your email address, please click here.

When I followed that on a new Apple ID that was recently established for my work, I did get signed up for a slew of emails by signing in to the device during automated setup and accepting the defaults.

Later, I decided to opt out from a link in the most recent email and now the web form says it may take up to 10 days to take full effect.

If you are still getting those mails after 10 days I would say your only avenue would be to contact Apple support. For what it's worth, my long time Apple ID didn't get any of these mails and only my new account which I did register and not opt out until the flurry of "black friday" November shopping emails made me decide I didn't need to see them for my work email either.

As you sign in to new devices, use extra caution to not sign in with the initial setup - that may make it hard to opt out of a few offers like free Apple TV with a new device purchase, etc... It's much easier to control those if you set up the device completely and then sign in only once the device is set up and past the "do everything for me" steps are done.

If they are phishing emails - following the links won't help and likely will hurt. I believe you always will get transactional emails from Apple even if you opt out of everything for a month or two and then decide to opt in for things you want again.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence that signing in at setup differs from signing in later? Have you observed differences in behavior?

Comment: I haven’t screen captured it, but I know it’s how I got subscribed from my new work phone. In the past, that’s also been my experience supporting people using Apple for the past 15 years @Ezekiel you can see some of this in the MDM listed under quick start - https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/manage-setup-assistant-depdeff4a547/web many of them are relevant for privacy warnings and opt in screen suppression. The consumer onboarding is not as customizable and it’s easy to opt in.

Comment: I think you may be on to something with signing in. Something I did got me a free trial of Apple Arcade and Fitness+ which is why they're bothering me, though I can't recall what it was that I did because I never intentionally signed up for any of those nor do I recall being told what I was doing would trigger any kind of trial.